# LJ18A3-8-Z/BX Proximity sensor Connection with ESP32

Tags: digital-logic, voltage-divider, esp32, level-shifting

I am using LJ18A3-8-Z/BX proximity sensor with ESP32 as Digital input. Issue is LJ18A3-8-Z/BX i dont know its esp32 compatible or not. I don't want to use resistor divider as it does not feel professional to me. Is there any other way that can help me integrate this sensor with esp32? I'll use 12V as power input to LJ18A3-8-Z/BX.
Datasheet of LJ18A3-8-Z/BX is: https://geeksvalley.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Proximity-Switch-LJ18A3-8-Z-BX.pdf

Comment: Why does a voltage divider feel unprofessional?

Comment: you can use an optocoupler, like the pros.

Comment: There seems to be three output options for the sensor - which one have you got?  You might want some input protection for the esp32. How long is the sensor wiring and what environment will it be used in?

Comment: sensor will not be longer than 100mm. one wire is of signal. most likely it will be 5V signal. level shifter would work here?